# CUDA driver issue

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am trying to do some computation with CUDA, I installed everything following the NVIDIA provided website installation page, everything should be fine, but I get the message "CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version" when I try to run the verification code "deviceQuery"

I read all other similar posts but it was not helpful.
I have the following:

Windows 7 64 bit
Visual Studio Community 2013
NVIDIA Quadro FX 3800
Driver installed version 341.95
Cuda 7.5 toolkit

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance
J.

Comment: Didn't you install the driver provided by the cuds installer?

Comment: Your GPU isn't supported by CUDA 7.5. You will need to install CUDA 6 or earlier to use that GPU with CUDA. This is really off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it as such.